# NestJs bcrypt.compare always return false using a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, typescript, nestjs, bcrypt

I am using:

- node v17.1
- nestjs 8.0.0
- bcrypt 5.0.1
- mssql 7.3.0

The problem is when I the user login. The user and password input are OK, but bcrypt compare return false.

Here is the code - this is the user entity:

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { BeforeInsert, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('users')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  readonly userId: string;

  @Column({
    unique: true,
  })
  readonly name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  password: string;

  @BeforeInsert()
  async hashPassword() {
    const temp = this.password.slice();
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
    const isValidUser = await bcrypt.compare(temp, this.password);
    console.log(`Comparacion resulta: ${isValidUser}`); // only for test isValid return true is credentials are OK
  }

  async validatePassword(password: string): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log(`Voy a comparar ${password} con ${this.password}`);// password and this password are OK
    const isValidUser = await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
    console.log(`Comparacion resulta: ${isValidUser}`); // for test only ALWAYS isValidUser es false
    return isValidUser;
  }

  constructor(userId: string, name: string, pass: string) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.name = name;
    this.password = pass;
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the data type of the `users.password` column? It needs to support at least 60 characters to store and retrieve the current resultant hashes from bcrypt.

Comment: users.password column is nvarchar(255). When I query to database for len of this field in database I got 60. This is right.

Comment: Problem solved. It was an error when I pass the password to bcrypt.hash method. I fix this and all work as expected, Thanks a lot to all.